# Saving PDF files through callback function in a spider in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Hi I have written the following code to extract url where pdf file lies and save the pdf through a callback function.
But my callback function-save_pdf never gets called.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class spider_aicte(BaseSpider):
    name = "Colleges"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.xyz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.xyz/appwebsite.html",
        "http://www.xyz/misappengineering.htm",
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            download_link = link.get('href')
            if '.pdf' in download_link:
                pdf_link = "http://www.xyz.org" + download_link
                print pdf_link
                print "pdf_link";
                for url in pdf_link:
                    print "inforLOOP-----pdflink"
                    yield Request(url, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def save_pdf(self, response):
         print "SAVING";
         path = self.get_path(response.url)
         with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            print "SAVED" ;
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over `pdf_link`? Just try `yield Request(pdf_link, callback=self.save_pdf)` instead of a loop.

Comment: Tried without loop also...still callback function never gets called

Comment: Since callback don't get called, there must something wrong with the Request. You should check the url parameter, the log. What's more, you can add a errback callback to see what happened.https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=request#scrapy.http.Request

Comment: @imwilsonxu Hi the url paramater is correct but I am getting empty body on response.May be this could be the reason callback never gets called.
but what could be the reason ? 
this is an example url i am trying to request for and the response body I am getting is null

http://www.aicte-india.org/downloads/approved_institut_websites/tri.pdf